# Why does the -v option with rm show entries with a backquote and a normal quote?

Tags: rm, stdout

When I do `rm -v` on a set of files, I see the output list of files being deleted with a backquote and a regular quote, eg:

```
rm -v rsl.out.0???
removed `rsl.out.0579'
removed `rsl.out.0580'
removed `rsl.out.0581'
```

I am curious to know if there is a deeper purpose in using different quotes instead of similar quotes or just no quotes.

Comment: On which system does it do that, because it doesn't on my Linux Mint 17.1: `removed ‘bla’`

Comment: This is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64), rm is GNU coreutils 8.12

Comment: I see this on an old Ubuntu 8.04 system as well

Comment: [verbose mode of rm](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-coreutils@gnu.org/msg07053.html)

Comment: My (OS X) manual pages do this all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through `lib/quotearg.c`  in the coreutils source reveals that the quoting is dependent on your `locale` setting. In my Linux Mint 17 (`en_GB.UTF-8`) I have both left and right quote the same (`‘`) whereas a system with `en_US.UTF-8` as locales have backquote before (left-of) the filename.

[This article](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sQuote.html) has some background